# Using parameter in PSQL

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a problem with using parameter in psql.
How to properly use the parameter in where clause.
There are no errors compiling the procedure which I listed below.
But no results when I pass 'bla bla bla' string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECTCATALOGUE (
 TXT  VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS (
 CODE VARCHAR(9),
 NAME VARCHAR(50))
AS 
BEGIN     
for execute statement
'select code,name
            from catalogue
            where name='||:TXT
into :CODE,:NAME
do 
   suspend;
END
```

But, when I execute this procedure by replacing the parameter for example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECTCATALOGUE (
 TXT  VARCHAR(30))
RETURNS (
 CODE VARCHAR(9),
 NAME VARCHAR(50))
AS 
BEGIN     
for execute statement
'select code,name
            from catalogue
            where name=''bla bla bla'''
into :CODE,:NAME
do 
   suspend;
END
```

I'm getting results properly. Am I missing something, how to make it work?

**EDIT:**
Ok, here is one more thing. This procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SELECTCATALOGUE
RETURNS (
 CODE VARCHAR(9),
 NAME VARCHAR(50))
AS 
declare variable stmt varchar(1000);
declare variable paramTXT varchar(100);
declare variable paramTXT1 varchar(100);
declare variable T varchar(1000);
BEGIN     
paramTXT='PLO'||'%';
paramTXT1='REM'||'%';
T='paramTXT,paramTXT1';
stmt='select code,name
            from catalogue
            where name like ? or name like ? order by name';
for execute statement (
  stmt
)
            (paramTXT,paramTXT1)
into :CODE,:NAME
do 
   suspend;
END
```

Gives me back proper results. Is there a way to use "T" string instead  "(paramTXT,paramTXT1)" and that can give me results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first version, you concatenate two strings which result in following string:

```
select code,name from catalogue where name=bla bla bla
```

You see that there is no quotes around the string `bla bla bla`, so the engine should treat it as a column name and usually this should result in a error like "column bla bla bla not found" or some such. If it happens that you send in an value which matches some column name then you would get empty resultset unless there is row(s) where the two columns have the same value.

To fix it, use parameterized statement:

```
for execute statement (
   'select code,name
            from catalogue
            where name = :parName')
   (parName := TXT)
   into :CODE,:NAME
do
```

See the [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-psql-coding.html#fblangref25-psql-execstmt) for the full syntax of the `execute statement`.

Comment: I have edited question (example above), sometimes it would not be only one parameter, so I thought that it might be good to use something like string to pass as a parameter. Is it possible?

Comment: Not while using parameterized statement. You could concatenate them to the statement (like your very first example but taking care to add quotes around the :TXT), but this is unsafe, better to use parameterized statement.