# Firebird SQL SUBSTRING : "expression evaluation not supported

Tags: sql, substring, firebird, unidac, firebird-3.0

I'm trying to run the following query on a database to replace the leading characters of certain rows.

```
UPDATE table SET path = :newpath || SUBSTRING(path FROM :pathlen) 
  WHERE path STARTING WITH :oldpath
```

So for parameter :newpath = foo, :oldpath = bar and :pathlen = 4, I want this

```
bar\wibble
```

to be changed to ...

```
foo\wibble
```

However, I get the error "expression evaluation not supported" and I'm not sure why. Replacing `:pathlen` with a literal `4` works correctly, so it's definitely the `SUBSTRING` causing the problem.

Comment: Whats the version of Firebird? Per [documentation](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-substring) "In Firebird 1.x, startpos and length must be integer literals. In 2.0 and above they can be any valid integer expression.".

Comment: Sorry, it's Firebird 3.0

Comment: Are you sure, because I just tested it with Firebird 3.0, and it works as expected. Are you executing this from a stored procedure, and if not: from which language?

Comment: Maybe there is little reason two duplicate parameters by having both `:oldpath` and `:pathlen` - just because of DRY thing, to void risk of giving them two inconsistent values. I'd prefer to use `char_length( :oldpath ) + 1` instead

Comment: @Arioch'The That's actually what I started with - but that was giving me a -804 "data type unknown" error :)  maybe something to do with this? http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1379

Comment: Correct. Then what about  `char_length( cast( :oldpath as VARCHAR(100) ) ) + 1` ?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Ah. I'm using Devart's UniDAC library, with Delph (OK, actually C++Builder) as the language. Maybe that's where the problems coming from?

Comment: Try the same code with other libs - DBX, UIB, Maybe FireDAC if your version has it

Comment: Also, may it depend upon fbclient.dll version, that the application loads ?

Comment: Also - can you use http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=execute_block to make OldPath and explicitly-typed parameter, thus suited for CHAR_LENGTH ?

Comment: also see this answer - perhaps that way it might get shorter than EXECUTE BLOCK - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39046420/976391

Comment: @Arioch'The FBClient 3.0.0.32483. Thanks for the help.